# Common datasources available to all JBoss instances

Tags: java, datasource, jboss5.x

We have a couple of JBoss instances using the same JBoss installation and would ask if its possible to declare a datasource(or JMS connection factory) in one location that will be available to all instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one data source definition and just you want to install it on all servers you can use one of these methods:

1. Use [RHQ](http://www.rhq-project.org/display/RHQ/Home) platform to monitor your JBoss server and deploy new application (and also data sources)
2. Use `twiddle` command (you can find in your JBoss `bin` directory) and `MainDeployer` bean:

   ```
   twiddle invoke "jboss.system:service=MainDeployer" deploy /some/path/myapp.ear
   ```

   Just remember that your data source should be accessible from server and will not be install after server restart - after each JBoss restart you need to tun these `twiddle` command. More info: [Application Deployment](http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/java_app/jboss5/jboss5_deployment.htm)
3. If your JBosses servers works in cluster you can try and use `farm` directory: [Farm Management](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/FarmManagement).
4. You can use SSH (or maybe FTP) server and copy the data source on each location. `scp` command can be very useful when you connect it with login by keys.
5. You can create some directory and export it by NFS. Than mount on each machine that directory and tell JBoss to deploy application from it. More info: [How to deploy my application in an external directory in JBoss-5](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToDeployMyApplicationInAnExternalDirectoryInJBoss-5).

Answer (score 1):

You can access the data source configured in one instance out side that instance. Check http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/beta500/html/ch13s15.html. Is this what you are looking for?